# how to sum column value using group by collection in magento(USING MAGENTO STANDARD)

Tags: magento

my table is like this and my collection is
$testmodel=Mage::getModel(test/p1)->getCollection();

```
     my database table is below.

    id  cat_id  rate   p_id
     1    1      4      1
     2    1      2      1
     3    1      3      2
     4    2      5      3
     5    2      3      1
```

and i want output like this in magento using collection

```
       cat_id  rate   count_category
         1      9       3
         2      8       2
```

Comment: can you please config.xml code in the question

Comment: no error in collection.but just i want to collection like above output.how can be filter for this output ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found my PROBLEM correct code is below

```
$testmodel = Mage::getModel('test/p1')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToSelect('rate')
                ->addFieldToSelect('cat_id');

            $testmodel ->getSelect()
                ->columns('SUM(rate) as total,COUNT(*) AS countCategory')
                ->group('cat_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use mysql4 as this model resource class then go to

**Model/Mysql4/P1/Collection.php**

**here you need to add function**

```
public function addGroupByCatId(){
      $subSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
      $CountsubSelect = clone $this->getSelect();

    $subSelect->reset()
        ->from(array('rev' => 'youtable', 'SUM( rev.rate)')
        ->where('main_table.cat_id = rev.cat_id');

        $CountsubSelect->reset()
        ->from(array('countrev' => 'youtable'),'COUNT(countrev.cat_id)')
        ->where('main_table.cat_id = countrev.cat_id');



    $this->getSelect()
        ->join(
            array('r' =>  'youtable'),
            'main_table.id = r.id',
            array(
                'review_sum'    => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('(%s)', $subSelect)),
                'count_category' =>  new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('(%s)', $CountsubSelect)),
                ))
        ->group('main_table.cat_id');
        return $this;

}
```

OR: Resouce as resource model then goto

if you use mysql4 as this model resource class then go to

**Model/Resource/P1/Collection.php**

**here you need to add function**

```
public function addGroupByCatId(){
      $subSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
      $CountsubSelect = clone $this->getSelect();

    $subSelect->reset()
        ->from(array('rev' => 'youtable', 'SUM( rev.rate)')
        ->where('main_table.cat_id = rev.cat_id');

        $CountsubSelect->reset()
        ->from(array('countrev' => 'youtable'),'COUNT(countrev.cat_id)')
        ->where('main_table.cat_id = countrev.cat_id');



    $this->getSelect()
        ->join(
            array('r' =>  'youtable'),
            'main_table.id = r.id',
            array(
                'review_sum'    => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('(%s)', $subSelect)),
                'count_category' =>  new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('(%s)', $CountsubSelect)),
                ))
        ->group('main_table.cat_id');
        return $this;

}
```

and final you get

```
 $testmodel=Mage::getModel(test/p1)->getCollection();
 $testmodel->addGroupByCatId();
```

Comment: and how t count  and sum rate(table field) column value similar cat_id ?

Comment: THANKS FOR HELP BUT I WANT TO OUTPUT WITHOUT MYSQL QUERY OR WITHOUT FROM,WHERE CLAUSE KEYWORD MEANS I WANT TO OUTPUT USING MAGENTO STANDARD WAY.

Comment: sorry.it not possible>if you  need with out usingthis above function,then you need run the the collection several times.

Comment: Hi, Amit Bera. I want to do same as your question. Dit you have solution to do that. Please share with me. Thank you so much!